# Google Maps API javascript V3 Uncaught type error: Type error

Tags: javascript, jquery, maps

In all major browsers my markers on my map work, but not in chrome. Sometimes they work, mostly they don't for no reason. The error i get is: Uncaught TypeError: Type error as in this link. http://d.pr/i/Ojxc

The links I get to the Main.js is the minified google api js file.
When i zoom out on my map i get the error over and over again. Zooming stops for no reason then, and then the map blocks.

In html everything is correct, the ajaxcall returns the correct data and it works in Safari, Opera, Firefox.

I am desperate here.

My js code:

```
function addStores(){

if(typeof google === 'object' && typeof google.maps === 'object'){
    try{
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url: api_url + '/locations',
            success: function(data){
                var stores = $.parseJSON(data);

                for(var i=0; i<stores.length; i++){
                    console.log("hallo");
                    var indi = i;
                    var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/store/pin_@2x.png', null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(32,50));
                    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(stores[i].latitude, stores[i].longitude);

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: myLatLng,
                        map:map,
                        icon: image,
                        tel: stores[i].tel,
                        state: stores[i].state,
                        street: stores[i].street
                    });

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
                        console.log("hkom");
                        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(marker.position.lat(), marker.position.lng()));
                        map.setZoom(15);

                        console.log("hallo");
                        opPinGeklikt(event, this);
                    });
                }

            },error:function(){
                console.log(arguments);
            }
        });

    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

}

Thx in advance.
W.

Comment: you should try to provide a jsfiddle, it's quite impossible otherwise to debug this kind of issue (working or not sometimes)

Comment: Can you give us a full test case with the HTML invoking the map? With such a generic error like that we'll need a complete scenario where we can step through it.

Comment: Sad that you've been -1 for asking a question?  I have the exact same problem and it only started a week or two ago with no changes to the website.  I've also noticed the same error on a competitor's website and only in chrome.  I'm using chrome "Version 27.0.1453.116 m".  Site is based on maps API v3, geoxml and ProjectedOverlay, loading placemarks from kml file, which load OK, but somewhere deep in map code get the above error.  NOTE: works fine in other browsers and was working a few weeks ago.

Comment: see: http://test.southfranceholidayvillas.co.uk/ and http://www.purefrance.com/languedoc-roussillon.php

Comment: so here is a cut down version, cannot use jsfiddle as the script gets a server-side kml file: http://test.southfranceholidayvillas.co.uk/kml/test.php

Comment: I found that I was also getting this error with a single map instance and got help on another thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17324072/google-maps-uncaught-typeerror-type-error) However, I can not see how to apply the marker options when loading from XML.  I have tried adding MarkerOptions:{optimized:false} to the map options but this doesn't make any difference.  ANY IDEAS?

Comment: @ChrisB I fixed it by reïnstalling my Chrome. I was testing it on another Macbook pro and it worked perfectly, so it had to be my own chrome. After reïnstalling everything worked perfectly. I have no explanation for it, just a solution. If it worked, please let me know.

Comment: @Warre Buysse - Yes, it worked!  Many thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make work in chrome add

> optimized: false

option to your marker.