# Why is my Google marker not showing up?

Tags: php, google-maps-markers

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY&sensor=false"></script>
        <script>
            var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(my_lat_echoed_from_php), parseFloat(my_lng_echoed_from_php));
            function initialize() {
                var mapOptions = {
                    center:myCenter,
                    zoom:6, 
                    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };

                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapOptions);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myCenter,
                    map: map,
                    title: 'Hello World!'
                });
            }
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="googleMap" style=" width:50%; height:500px; border:3px solid black; margin: 0 auto;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It gets the latitude and longitude correctly from my database and centers it on the correct place, but no marker shows up. I am including `locations_show.php` for this HTML page. Everything works except the marker.

Comment: Any errors in your browser error console? Your `myCenter` LatLng point is correctly centering the map on your location (which indicates your PHP coords are correctly output)?

Comment: Yes. Since I started using the Google map, I have been getting this error in my console: "Uncaught TypeError: Type error". I thought nothing of it because everything had been working fine (except when I tried using the marker).

Comment: Actually, I just fixed it. I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17324072/google-maps-uncaught-typeerror-type-error and added optimized: false to my marker options

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added `optimized: false` to my marker options as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17324809/2554416).

**Changed this:**

```
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myCenter,
    map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
});
```

**To**

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myCenter,
    map: map,
    optimized: false,
    title: 'Hello World!'
});
```